# Water Droplet Size Explosion

Tags: water, explosions

How do I control the droplet size in a water balloon during a midair explosion?
In other words: can the droplet size be influenced by the choice of explosive inside the water balloon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The droplet size is mostly dependent on the   nozzle diameter. In case of an explosion, it's much dependent on the conditions in which the explosion occurs ( presence of external pressure, radius of water balloon...)

Finer droplets are also generated by liquids with lower viscosity and higher surface tension